# Task Distribution

Tags: python, data, algorithms, distribution

I would like to distribute tasks (going to companies and signing a deal) to sales representatives based on some condition like company location (is it near the representative's place) or profit of the deal. In such a way that every sales reps are assigned equal tasks and profit gains. What algorithm can I use in Py? Any reference examples would help.

Comment: Are you trying to improve a series of tasks or just tasks independently?

Comment: This is certainly an optimization problem, genetic learning is usually a good direction. You will need to specify the problem and define an evaluation method, it's not going to work out of the box.